# How to wait for an action to go through reducer?

Tags: redux

I'm using redux and redux-thunk.

I have the following code:

```
export function initialAuth() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(authApp()).then(
      (token) => {
          dispatch(fetchUserProfile(token)).then(() => {
            dispatch(displayUserProfile(token))
        })
      }
    )
  }
}
```

The problem that I have is that `dispatch(displayUserProfile(token))` only waits for the action to be dispatched, but doesn't wait for that action to go through reducer.

I actually need the action to go through reducer and then dispatch the other action. How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [redux-saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga), you'll be able to handle side effects much more easily using generators instead of callbacks.